# How to make a div float over another div as this image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying with any success at all to achieve something like this

this is using desktop
http://i.imgur.com/mYMNxza.png

and this one is for mobile view
http://i.imgur.com/XszUTe5.png

how to make this? If it's possible to use Twitter Bootstrap would be awesome to me....

Cheers and thanks in advance  =D

Comment: please add relevant code and whatever code you've tried.

Comment: display:block;  is your friend

Comment: sorry guys.... after I sent this message I left my home for an emergency and only returned a few minutes ago.... but now, the answer is done already.... thanks and sorry for that =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop on this code;
http://codepen.io/ogzhncrt/pen/xGBGPL

```
<div class="gn">
  <div class="tx">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="in">
    <div class="tx">
      1
    </div>
 </div>
</div>

<style>
body {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.gn {
  width: 800px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: rgb(34,34,34);
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  padding: 40px;
}

.in {
  background-color: #f79779;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
}

.tx {
  font-size: 172px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right:120px;
}

@media (max-width:700px){
  .gn {
    padding:0px;
    width:400px;
  }
  .tx {
    padding-right:60px;
   } 
  .in {
    width:400px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: perfect solution!! thanks very much! =D